# Loosing xml content when POST to wcf REST

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

am loosing xml content when calling wcf service via post. I see only "<" to wcf method. Am passing xml content like this: samplesample.

**Client:**

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:48677/MYSVC.svc/ParseXML/<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?><node>sample</node><node1>sample</node1>',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: true,
        success: function (msg) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
```

Service Interface:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "ParseXML/{xmlContent}")]
    Stream ParseXML(string xmlContent);
```

Also incorporated wrapper as per: http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/wcf-rest-service-accepting-raw-xml-webcontenttypemapper/

If I pass non-xml string, my service get called but proper xml content it is not.

Also included following line in both service & asp.net web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxUrlLength="4096" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="2147483647" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" executionTimeout="18000" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

I also tried with this: requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,:,\,?" but didn't help

Please guide me how to pass proper xml content to wcf!

**Updated:**

WHile calling service from httpwebresponse, am getting below error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Incoming message for operation 'ParseXML' (contract
>   'IXmlParseService' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an
>   unrecognized http body format value 'Xml'. The expected body format
>   value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not
>   been configured on the binding. See the documentation of
>   WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.GetStreamFromMessage(Message
>   message, Boolean isRequest) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not being properly encoded for url use. You can use encodeURIComponent() to encode the content.

```
var payload=encodeURIComponent('<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?><node>sample</node><node1>sample</node1>');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:48677/MYSVC.svc/ParseXML/'+payload,
    data:{'xmlContent':payload},
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: true,
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function (err) {
    }
});
```

Comment: If I call via ajax, it works even without encodeURIComponent. Please refer to updated error message in original question

Comment: Do you have the proper webHttpBinding and service behavior for xml defined in your service configuration?